# userns container fails to start, how to track down the reason?

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, userns

When creating a userns (unprivileged) LXC container on Ubuntu 14.04 with the following command line:

```
lxc-create -n test1 -t download -- -d $(lsb_release -si|tr 'A-Z' 'a-z') -r $(lsb_release -sc) -a $(dpkg --print-architecture)
```

and (without touching the created configuration file) then attempting to start it with:

```
lxc-start -n test1 -l DEBUG
```

it fails. The log file shows me:

```
lxc-start 1420149317.700 INFO     lxc_start_ui - using rcfile /home/user/.local/share/lxc/test1/config
lxc-start 1420149317.700 INFO     lxc_utils - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR isn't set in the environment.
lxc-start 1420149317.701 INFO     lxc_confile - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
lxc-start 1420149317.701 INFO     lxc_confile - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
lxc-start 1420149317.701 WARN     lxc_log - lxc_log_init called with log already initialized
lxc-start 1420149317.701 INFO     lxc_lsm - LSM security driver AppArmor
lxc-start 1420149317.701 INFO     lxc_utils - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR isn't set in the environment.
lxc-start 1420149317.702 DEBUG    lxc_conf - allocated pty '/dev/pts/2' (5/6)
lxc-start 1420149317.702 DEBUG    lxc_conf - allocated pty '/dev/pts/7' (7/8)
lxc-start 1420149317.702 DEBUG    lxc_conf - allocated pty '/dev/pts/8' (9/10)
lxc-start 1420149317.702 DEBUG    lxc_conf - allocated pty '/dev/pts/10' (11/12)
lxc-start 1420149317.702 INFO     lxc_conf - tty's configured
lxc-start 1420149317.702 DEBUG    lxc_start - sigchild handler set
lxc-start 1420149317.702 DEBUG    lxc_console - opening /dev/tty for console peer
lxc-start 1420149317.702 DEBUG    lxc_console - using '/dev/tty' as console
lxc-start 1420149317.702 DEBUG    lxc_console - 14946 got SIGWINCH fd 17
lxc-start 1420149317.702 DEBUG    lxc_console - set winsz dstfd:14 cols:118 rows:61
lxc-start 1420149317.905 INFO     lxc_start - 'test1' is initialized
lxc-start 1420149317.906 DEBUG    lxc_start - Not dropping cap_sys_boot or watching utmp
lxc-start 1420149317.906 INFO     lxc_start - Cloning a new user namespace
lxc-start 1420149317.906 INFO     lxc_cgroup - cgroup driver cgmanager initing for test1
lxc-start 1420149317.907 ERROR    lxc_cgmanager - call to cgmanager_create_sync failed: invalid request
lxc-start 1420149317.907 ERROR    lxc_cgmanager - Failed to create hugetlb:test1
lxc-start 1420149317.907 ERROR    lxc_cgmanager - Error creating cgroup hugetlb:test1
lxc-start 1420149317.907 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: hugetlb:test1 did not exist
lxc-start 1420149317.908 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: perf_event:test1 did not exist
lxc-start 1420149317.908 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: blkio:test1 did not exist
lxc-start 1420149317.908 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: freezer:test1 did not exist
lxc-start 1420149317.909 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: devices:test1 did not exist
lxc-start 1420149317.909 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: memory:test1 did not exist
lxc-start 1420149317.909 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: cpuacct:test1 did not exist
lxc-start 1420149317.909 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: cpu:test1 did not exist
lxc-start 1420149317.910 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: cpuset:test1 did not exist
lxc-start 1420149317.910 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: name=systemd:test1 did not exist
lxc-start 1420149317.910 ERROR    lxc_start - failed creating cgroups
lxc-start 1420149317.910 INFO     lxc_utils - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR isn't set in the environment.
lxc-start 1420149317.910 ERROR    lxc_start - failed to spawn 'test1'
lxc-start 1420149317.910 INFO     lxc_utils - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR isn't set in the environment.
lxc-start 1420149317.910 INFO     lxc_utils - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR isn't set in the environment.
lxc-start 1420149317.910 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - The container failed to start.
lxc-start 1420149317.910 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

Now I see two errors here, the latter probably being a result of the former, which is:

> lxc_start - failed creating cgroups

However, I see `/sys/fs/cgroup` mounted:

```
$ mount|grep cgr
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
```

and `cgmanager` is installed:

```
$ dpkg -l|awk '$1 ~ /^ii$/ && /cgmanager/ {print $2 " " $3 " " $4}'
cgmanager 0.24-0ubuntu7 amd64
libcgmanager0:amd64 0.24-0ubuntu7 amd64
```

Note: My host defaults still to `upstart`.

In case there's any doubt, the kernel support `cgroups`:

```
$ grep CGROUP /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
# CONFIG_CGROUP_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED=y
CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_BLK_CGROUP is not set
CONFIG_NET_CLS_CGROUP=m
CONFIG_NETPRIO_CGROUP=m
```

Note: My host defaults still to `upstart`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out, surprise surprise, this is a Ubuntu-specific thing.

---

### The cause

The problem: although the kernel has `cgroups` enabled (check with `grep CGROUP /boot/config-$(uname -r)`) and `cgmanager` is running, there is no cgroup specific to my user. You can check that with:

```
$ cat /proc/self/cgroup
11:hugetlb:/
10:perf_event:/
9:blkio:/
8:freezer:/
7:devices:/
6:memory:/
5:cpuacct:/
4:cpu:/
3:name=systemd:/
2:cpuset:/
```

if your UID is given in each of the relevant lines, it's alright, but if no cgroups have been defined there will only be a slash after the second colon on each line.

My problem was specific to starting an unprivileged container. I could start privileged containers just fine.

It turned out that my problem was closely related to [this thread on the `lxc-users` mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.containers.lxc.general/6741).

### Remedy

On Ubuntu 14.04 `upstart` is the default, as opposed to `systemd`. Hence certain components that would be installed on a `systemd`-based distro do not get installed by default.

There were two packages in addition to `cgmanager` which I had to install in order to get beyond the error shown in my question: `cgroup-bin` and `libpam-systemd`. Quite frankly I am not 100% certain that the former is strictly needed, so you could try to leave it out and comment here.

After the installation of the packages and a reboot, you should then see your UID (`id -u`, here 1000) in the output:

```
$ cat /proc/self/cgroup
11:hugetlb:/user/1000.user/1.session
10:perf_event:/user/1000.user/1.session
9:blkio:/user/1000.user/1.session
8:freezer:/user/1000.user/1.session
7:devices:/user/1000.user/1.session
6:memory:/user/1000.user/1.session
5:cpuacct:/user/1000.user/1.session
4:cpu:/user/1000.user/1.session
3:name=systemd:/user/1000.user/1.session
2:cpuset:/user/1000.user/1.session
```

After that, the error upon attempting to start the guest container becomes (trimmed for brevity):

```
lxc-start 1420160065.383 INFO     lxc_cgroup - cgroup driver cgmanager initing for test1
lxc-start 1420160065.419 ERROR    lxc_start - failed to create the configured network
lxc-start 1420160065.446 ERROR    lxc_start - failed to spawn 'test1'
lxc-start 1420160065.451 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - The container failed to start.
```

So still no success, but we're one step closer.

The above linked `lxc-users` thread points to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` not mentioning three controllers: `net_cls`, `net_prio` and `debug`. For me only the last one was missing. After the change you'll have to re-login, though, as the the changes take effect upon creation of your login session.

This blog post by one of the authors of LXC gives the next step:

> Your user, while it can create new user namespaces in which it’ll be
>   uid 0 and will have some of root’s privileges against resources tied
>   to that namespace will obviously not be granted any extra privilege on
>   the host.
>
> One such thing is creating new network devices on the host or changing
>   bridge configuration. To workaround that, we wrote a tool called
>   “lxc-user-nic” which is the only SETUID binary part of LXC 1.0 and
>   which performs one simple task.  It parses a configuration file and
>   based on its content will create network devices for the user and
>   bridge them. To prevent abuse, you can restrict the number of devices
>   a user can request and to what bridge they may be added.
>
> An example is my own /etc/lxc/lxc-usernet file:
>
> ```
> stgraber veth lxcbr0 10
> ```
>
> This declares that the user “stgraber” is allowed up to 10 veth type
>   devices to be created and added to the bridge called lxcbr0.
>
> Between what’s offered by the user namespace in the kernel and that
>   setuid tool, we’ve got all that’s needed to run most distributions
>   unprivileged.

If your user has `sudo` rights and you're using Bash, use this:

```
echo "$(whoami) veth lxcbr0 10"|sudo tee -a /etc/lxc/lxc-usernet
```

and make sure the type (`veth`) matches the one in the container config and the bridge (`lxcbr0`) is configured and up.

And now we get another set of errors:

```
lxc-start 1420192192.775 INFO     lxc_start - Cloning a new user namespace
lxc-start 1420192192.775 INFO     lxc_cgroup - cgroup driver cgmanager initing for test1
lxc-start 1420192192.923 NOTICE   lxc_start - switching to gid/uid 0 in new user namespace
lxc-start 1420192192.923 ERROR    lxc_start - Permission denied - could not access /home/user.  Please grant it 'x' access, or add an ACL for the container root.
lxc-start 1420192192.923 ERROR    lxc_sync - invalid sequence number 1. expected 2
lxc-start 1420192192.954 ERROR    lxc_start - failed to spawn 'test1'
lxc-start 1420192192.959 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - The container failed to start.
```

Brilliant, that can be fixed. [Another `lxc-users` thread](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-users/2014-May/006784.html) by the same protagonists as in the first thread paves the way.

For now a quick test `sudo chmod -R o+X $HOME` will have to do, but ACLs are a viable option here as well. YMMV.

Comment: I'm still stuck by the fact that if I want to run userns LXC container as another user, it fails. Creation works (with one warning: `WARN: could not reopen tty: Permission denied`). But starting `sudo -H -i -u database lxc-start -n mysql -d` fails like in your question. Same errors. However your fix does not work with `sudo`. If I do `sudo -H -i -u database cat /proc/self/cgroup` I get the exact same output as if I run it as my calling user. So obviously, when trying to start the container using sudo, it will try as the other user to write in my cgroup which fails... :-( Any insight?